STM32CubeIDE: How to exclude memory sections in linker script from output file
In my cube project, I need to generate a bin file as the output.  The output bin file is over 2GB because it includes a RAM section (0x30000000) in the output as well as the required flash section (0x90000000)
The linker script has the following section, which I believe to be the culprit:
  .dma_buffer :
  {
    *(.dma_buffer)
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >RAM_D2

and this is the memory definition:
MEMORY
{
  DTCMRAM      (xrw)    : ORIGIN = 0x20000000,   LENGTH = 128K
  ITCMRAM      (xrw)    : ORIGIN = 0x00000000,   LENGTH = 64K
  RAM_D1       (xrw)    : ORIGIN = 0x24000000,   LENGTH = 512K
  RAM_D2       (xrw)    : ORIGIN = 0x30000000,   LENGTH = 288K
  RAM_D3       (xrw)    : ORIGIN = 0x38000000,   LENGTH = 64K
  SDRAM        (xrw)    : ORIGIN = 0xD0000000,   LENGTH = 8M
  FLASH        (xrw)    : ORIGIN = 0x90000000,   LENGTH = 2048K
  ASSETS_FLASH (r)      : ORIGIN = 0x90200000,   LENGTH = 62M
}

How can I modify this linker script to exclude the 0x30000000 region from the output file?

I seem to have fixed this by adding (NOLOAD) to this section:
  .dma_buffer (NOLOAD) :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.dma_buffer)
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >RAM_D2

Let me know if anybody has more insight into this.
